# Completing VBA Userform textboxes from Excel Cell

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I'm trying to fill in a userform ("Userform1") textboxes ("SecurityTextBox", "VersionTextbox") from an Excel Sheet ("Version"). I've tried to look up what's going wrong but I haven't managed to figure it out.

```
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Version")

SecurityTextBox.Text = ws.Cells.Range("C8").Value
VersionTextbox.Text = ws.Cells.Range("C13").Value
DeveloperTextBox.Text = ws.Cells.Range("C14").Value

End Sub
```

The trouble is the text boxes are just appearing blank.

Comment: What *is* happening when you run this? Anything? Where does it fail?

Comment: Get rid of `Cells.` in your range pointers - `ws.Range("C8").Value` should work just fine

Comment: You very likely don't *want* the UserForm to even *know* there's a worksheet with these values - the form needs values, not cells. You want to be able to bring up the form even if the data moves elsewhere, without needing to change anything about how the form works. [This SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/1335170/165271) shows how.

Comment: That said, you need to [edit] your question so that we know specifically *what* isn't working, and *how* you know it. Since this is the `_Initialize` handler, it runs when the class/form instance is created. If you're invoking the *default instance* of the form, it's probably not giving you the values you're expecting. `With New UserForm1` ... `.Show` ... `End With` at the call site, should invoke the `_Initialize` handler as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The `_Initialize` handler is invoked when the class/form instance is created. If you're showing the form like this:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

Then it *might* work as expected if that's the only thing you're ever doing with the form. Problem is, it's the form's *default instance*, and you don't quite control *when* VBA is going to initialize that global instance.

Take control.

```
With New UserForm1 'initializes a new instance of the class
    .Show
End With
```

Now the `_Initialize` handler with systematically run every time, because it's a `New` instance every time. See my [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) article for more pitfalls of using forms' default instances.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've made the changes set out above but still not having any luck. Will edit the question to outline, I think that's the best way to set out

Comment: You're reading off the active sheet. Is it the sheet you're expecting/need? ActiveSheet dependencies break down rather easily.